# Can't Install Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-10

When I run the VS2010 installer, nothing opens. I checked my running processes and I do not see anything new in there either.

I have tried running it in compatibility mode for 8, 8.1, and 7. I have also tried running it as an administrator. Same problem. Opening the setup causes nothing to happen.

I am on the latest Windows 10 build (10122), the previous build did not work either.

Does anyone have any ideas or know how to fix this?

Thank you.

Edit: I'm actually having the same problem in a copy of Windows 8.1 I'm running in Hyper-V.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Opening the iso and running setup.exe or autorun.exe does not work. Instead, running ~/Setup/setup.exe worked.

That is, the setup.exe in the Setup folder works. However, the setup.exe in the root folder does not work.