# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 incompatible with Windows 10?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

This is my PC's OS:

[image: win 10]

I try to Install vs 2010, then run it, then this dialog appears:

[image: vs]

Then, I try to download vs2010 sp1 (the filename is: VS2010SP1dvd (iso image))

I try to install vs2010 sp1, then this dialog appears:

[image: sp1]

I try to find ways to install vs2010 sp1, but no clue.
I read the docs:

```
Supported Operating Systems:

Windows XP (x86) with Service Pack 3 - all editions except Starter Edition
Windows Vista (x86 and x64) with Service Pack 2 - all editions except Starter Edition
Windows 7 (x86 and x64)
Windows Server 2003 (x86 and x64) with Service Pack 2 - all editions
MSXML6 must be installed
Windows Server 2003 R2 (x86 and x64) - all editions
Windows Server 2008 (x86 and x64) with Service Pack 2 - all editions
Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64) - all editions
```

But, maybe that info is wrong? Maybe anybody know how to solve this case?

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381602/cant-install-visual-studio-2010-on-windows-10) from stack overflow answers. It might help.

Comment: Thank You, @debatanu. hope this work well. Now, vs 2010 installed. I am not so sure are all of the functionalities work or not. But, thank you for your guidance.